# Wrap 2 symbols in span tags for all hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(".cms-outdoor-furniture-covers .col-main a").each(function (i, html) {
  return html.replace(" >", "<span class=\"no-underline\">$&</span>");
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to replace all `" >"` in hyperlinks with `"<span class="no-underline"> ></span>"`

markup:

```
<div class="cms-outdoor-furniture-covers">
    <div class="col-main">
        <a href="#"> random text ending with ></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Goal I want to achieve is- keep underline for random string, but wrap ending- " >" in span to remove underline from there.

```
<div class="cms-outdoor-furniture-covers">
    <div class="col-main">
        <a href="#"> random text ending with<span class="no-underline"> ></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please place your html and output of html you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to do:

```
jQuery(".cms-outdoor-furniture-covers .col-main a").each(function (i, val) {
    var html = jQuery(this).html();
    if( html.search(' &gt;') > -1 ) {
        jQuery(this).html( "<span class='no-underline'>" + html.replace( " &gt;", "" ) + "</span>" + " >" );
    }
});
```

and CSS:

```
a { text-decoration: none }
.no-underline {text-decoration:underline;}
```

You need to remove the underline from the link altogether (narrow down the CSS to only affect those links if you want) and then add a class to the text you want underlined instead.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qz5R8/2/

Comment: @bazinga what is your html markup and what should be resulted please update.

Comment: @bazinga - check again, please :)

Comment: tis one works,thanks, only 1 more problem, it also adds " >" after `<img>` , I have narrowed it down to a.learnmore, but link to image has same class.

Comment: You can check for the > and only apply the search to elements that have it. I've updated above. @bazinga

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the a-tags:

```
$('.cms-outdoor-furniture-covers .col-main a')
.wrap("<span class='no-underline'></span>");
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to wrap the text not a tag.